# Создание макрос-функции в C++

Tags: c++

Задача стоит написать функцию-макрос. Сама функция написано и даже один раз корректно срабатывает. 
Вот она:

```
#define maximum(x, y, r) int aa=x; int bb=y; r = ((aa) > (bb) ? (aa) : (bb))/* присвойте в r максимум из x и y */
```

Но при повторном вызове компилятор выдает ошибки вида:

```
error: redeclaration of 'int aa'
error: 'int aa' previously declared here
```

Помогите разобраться в причине, пожалуйста

Comment: каждый раз как вы используете свой макрос он заново размещает одни и те же переменные в одном пространстве имен несколько раз, т.е два раза вызвали получили    int aa=x; int bb=y;    int aa=x; int bb=y;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Прежде всего мне представляется, что вы имели в виду что-то подобное:

```
#define maximum(x, y, r) \
do { int aa = ( x ); int bb = ( y ); ( r ) = bb < aa ? aa : bb; } while ( false )
```

Предвидя ваш вопрос, почему используется конструкция `do-while`, скажу, чтобы, например, этот макрос можно было бы использовать в `if-else` предложении:

```
if ( x > 0 && y > 0 ) maimum( x, y, r );
else maximum( x = -x, y = -y, r );
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

#define maximum(x, y, r) \
do { int aa = ( x ); int bb = ( y ); ( r ) = bb < aa ? aa : bb; } while ( false )

int main()
{
    int x = -10, y = -5, r;

    if ( x > 0 && y > 0 ) maximum( x, y, r );
    else maximum( x = -x, y = -y, r );

    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << ", r = " << r << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
x = 10, y = 5, r = 10
```

Что касается вашего определения макроса, то он постоянно определяет переменные `aa` и `bb` в той области видимости, где макрос вызывается.

```
#define maximum(x, y, r) int aa=x; int bb=y; r = ((aa) > (bb) ? (aa) : (bb))
```

Поэтому компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке, что эти переменные были уже определены, если макрос вызывается более одного раза.

Использование макросов в C++ - это анахронизм. Лучше использовать встраиваемые  функции, то есть функции со спецификатором `inline`. Более того в C++ уже есть стандартная функция `std::max`. Поэтому вы могли бы просто написать

```
r = std::max( x, y );
```

Имейте в виду, что поведение вашего макроса отличается от поведения аналогичной стандартной функции `std::max`. Ваш макрос в случае равенства `x` и `y` возвращает `y`, тогда как стандартная функция `std::max` возвращает `x`. И кроме того вы используете оператор `>` тогда как стандартная функция использует оператор `<`. Для фундаментальных типов это может не играть существенной роли, тогда как для определенных пользователем типов это имеет важное значение.

А самое главное - ваш макрос нельзя использовать в выражениях. Это ограничивает его применение.

Comment: Скобки-скобки-скобки...

Comment: онлайновые функции :))))

Answer (score 3):

Причина однозначно описана в сообщении об ошибке: множественное объявление переменной. Макрос заменяется (грубо говоря) на его содержимое препроцессором и у вас второй раз появляется объявление переменной как только появляется второе вхождение макроса.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define SET_MAX(r,a,b) do \
                         { \
                         auto aa=(a); \
                         auto bb=(b); \
                         (r) = aa>bb ? aa : bb; \
                         } while(0)
```

Но вообще, лучше сделать функцию:

```
template <typename typed>
typed & set_max(typed &r, const typed &a, const typed &b)
  {
  return r = a > b ? a : b;
  }
```

Comment: Скобки излишни.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов, 1. нет. 2. какие именно?

Comment: В 3-й строке первого примера.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов, ошибку я уже сам поправил, а про скобки подумаю.

Comment: Подумай. Там есть над чем.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А не нужно ли `auto&`? Чтобы избежать ненужного копирования?

Comment: @VladD, тогда уж `const auto &`? Но что-то я опасаюсь такое без проверки писать...

Comment: `const auto&` будет означать, что вернётся const-объект. А это может оказаться неправильно.

Comment: @VladD, а если объект уже был константным, то `auto` это разгребёт? Например, `auto &aa = (1);`? Вот из-за подобных сомнений я и не стал ссылку пихать.

Comment: @VladD, и вообще, как-то это нехорошо, если константные объекты нельза сравнивать на больше/меньше, а неконстантные можно.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов, хотя и извращение, но вот про скобки: https://ideone.com/PXJFLW

Comment: @Qwertiy, если не знать что такое COMMA, то параметры макроса не очевидны. Если знать что такое COMMA, то мы знаем что передаём в макрос. Пример ни о чём не говорит, не говоря уже о том, что никто в здравом уме такое писать не будет.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов, чем тебе мешают эти скобки? Я привёл пример не того, что все будут писать, а того, что в принципе возможно, что их отсутствие скажется на результате. "Если знать что такое COMMA, то мы знаем что передаём в макрос." - да, мы знаем, _что_ мы передаём, но мы ожидаем, что он это _корректно_ обработает. И он может корректно обработать. Но вариант без скобок обрабатывает некорректно. Так что плохого в наличии этих скобок? Либо есть какой-то случай, когда они мешают (но я такого не вижу, покажи тогда), либо нет никаких причин их убирать - ведь так?

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю и свои 5 копеек.

Для GNU (g++/gcc) я бы написал этот макрос следующим образом:

```
#define maximum(x, y, r) ({typeof(x) _x = x; typeof(y) _y = y; \
      (r) = ( _x > _y ? _x : _y);})
```

Компиляторы g++/gcc позволяют использовать  блоки `{...}`,  в которых можно определять локальные для блока переменные,  в скобочных выражениях.

В таком виде у макроса будет такое  же поведение как у функции, если его аргументы "самомодифицирующиеся", т.е. Вы пишете что-то типа

```
maximum(++a, b--, *t++);
```

Поскольку тело макроса заключено в скобки, то его можно использовать в коде всюду, где допустимо *выражение*, например, в операторе `if`

```
if (maximum(a, b, t[i++]) > 0))
  ....
```

или в качестве аргумента функций, в объявлении переменных (инициализация) и т.п. как функцию с побочным эффектом.

Значением такого выражения будет значение последнего оператора, т.е. то, что в данном случае присваивается аргументу `r` макроса. Понятно, что `r` в этом макросе д.б. [lvalue](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

P.S.
Между прочим, тип выражений (переменных) x, y и r *может быть и разным*.

Comment: Тут про скобки у аргументов что-то спор возник, но вот уж у `r` скобки совершенно точно нужны. `(a<b ? a : b) = c>d ? c : d;`

Comment: А про разные типы я уже подумал, поэтому в своём варианте поменял одно auto на два. Для шаблона тоже можно несколько параметров типа сделать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, там где аргументы макроса используются в арифметических выражениях, сравнении и т.п. скобки точно нужны. А для правильного lvalue зачем они? Хотя, поскольку мировой запас скобок не ограничен, то во всех сомнительных случаях их стоит использовать. / Здесь же (в моем  макро) imho для `r` они не нужны. Т.е. попробуйте найти такую конструкцию для r, которая со скобками работает, а без них нет (мне такая что-то в голову не приходит (на самом деле буду рад ошибиться и увидеть ее)).

Comment: `maximum(c, d, x<y?x:y);` - это же си++, а не си - тут выражение тоже может давать lvalue.

Comment: А ещё, явно не в сишных традициях присваиваемый аргумент писать последним, а не первым - вспомнить тот же strcpy. Но это к автору вопроса.

Comment: @Qwertiy, OK, убедили, подправлю. Хотя, мне все же кажется, что в таком случае программисту правильнее было бы заключать в скобки подобное выражение (`x<y?x:y`) при вызова макроса.

Comment: В случае функции оно бы работало и без скобок. Если цель - максимально приблизить макрос к функции, то скобки при вызове не нужны. Да и вообще, ничего, что не содержит top level запятой заключать в скобки при передаче как аргумента мне логичным не кажется :)

Answer (score 1):

Макрос - это не функция. Проще сделать так:

```
#define maximum(x, y, r) r = ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
```

И не забудь добавить **;** после **maximum** при использовании.

Но обычно делают так:

```
#define maximum(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
```

А используют так:

```
int r = maximum( a, b );
```

Но раз уж мы говорим о С++, то я бы использовал функцию.

```
template <class T> T & maximum( T & a, T & b ) { return a > b ? a : b; }
```

Comment: там в тестах прединкрименты стоят. Например вот так:

'int a = 16;
    int b = 20;
    'int c = 0;

    'maximum (++a, ++b, c);'

И суть в том чтобы он и с ними корректно срабатывал - то есть не инкрементил два раза a например!

Я только через введение доп переменных могу так сделать.

Comment: @АлександрДворцов, ну тогда сам Бог велел заменить этот макрос на функцию.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define maximum(x, y) []() { auto aa=(x),  bb=(y); return  ((aa) > (bb) ? (aa) : (bb)); }()
```

:)

Comment: Поясните свой ответ пожалуйста

Comment: Плюсик, за то что прикольно :)

Comment: Лямбда в макросе. Сочетание жесть)